# How to use an array inside another array in scala in order to use each element from one array to append to corresponding element from other array?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, nested-loops, scala-collections

first array:
var keyColumns = "A,B".split(",")

second array:
var colValues = DataFrameTest.select("Y","Z").collect.map(row => row.toString)
colValues: Array[String]= Array([1,2],[3,4],[5,6])

I want something as a result like:
Array([A=1,B=2],[A=3,B=4],[A=5,B=6])

so that later I can iterate over this Array and can create my where clause like
where
(A=1 AND B=2) OR (A=3 AND B=4) OR (A=5 AND B=6)

Answer (score 1):

First, don't convert structured data to string. Do `.map(_.toSeq)` after collect, not `toString`.

Then, something like this should work:

```
   colValues
     .map { _ zip keyColumns } 
     .map { _.map { case (v,k) => s"$k=$v" } }
     .map { _.mkString("(", " AND ", ")") }
     .mkString(" OR ")
```

You may find it helpful to run this step-by-step in REPL and see what each line does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the code snippet. It helps but .join does not work, 'value join is not a member of Seq[String]'
 I tried using map as below in place of join
.map { _.map { e => e.split(",").mkString(" AND ")}
It does not throw any error but it is not doing anything. When tried explicitly on the similar string, it works but not inside the chained transformations.

Comment: ugh, sorry ... `mksString`, not `join` ... I alway confuse these between different languages :) I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex expression, like:

```scala
scala> val keyColumns = "A,B".split(",")
keyColumns: Array[String] = Array(A, B)

scala> val colValues = "[1,2] [3,4] [5,6]".split(" ")
colValues: Array[String] = Array([1,2], [3,4], [5,6])

scala> val pattern = """^\[(.{1}),(.{1})\]$""".r //here, (.{1}) determines a regex group of exactly 1 any char
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^\[(.{1}),(.{1})\]$

scala> colValues.map { e => pattern.findFirstMatchIn(e).map { m => s"(${keyColumns(0)}=${m.group(1)} AND ${keyColumns(1)}=${m.group(2)})" }.getOrElse(e) }.mkString(" OR ")
res0: String = (A=1 AND B=2) OR (A=3 AND B=4) OR (A=5 AND B=6)
```

Comment: "(.{1}) determines a regex group of exactly 1 any char" -- and so does just `.` :D Or `(.)` if you want group.